# Integration of Whmcs with Cloud Stack

Tags: integration, whmcs, apache-cloudstack

forgive me for asking a amateur question (if it is)
i need to know how can i integrate **WHMCS with Cloud Stack**
can any one guide me through generic steps involved 
do i need to configure whmcs or cloud stack
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our company has build billing module on WHMCS. Use [this](http://docs.whmcs.com/Developer_Resources) resource for development.

Answer (score 1):

These two will do what you are looking for:

- WHMCS:
  http://www.whmcs.com/appstore/818/CloudStack-Pre-Billing-and-Provisioning.html
- Hostbill: http://hostbillapp.com/features/apps/cloudstack.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Anolim i already contacted  Whmcs for that module and its a third party module  and they said they have stopped devleopment on that... and Hostbill is not the solution for us